# Programmatically change boot logo in Android

Tags: java, android

As I know there are 3 types of logos in Android boot process.
How can I change them from my application?
I tried to change bootanimation.zip, but without success.

I have rooted Ross&Moor rmd-713 tablet.

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out? I'm still wondering myself. I tried the following with no success: 
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/xbin/su","-c", 
"cp", "/system/media/customBootAnimation.zip", 
"/system/media/bootanimation.zip"});`

Answer (score 0):

Its better to install a bootanimation from your Sdcard opposed to from inside the system directory, so like this.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
    "/system/xbin/su","-c", "cp",
    "/mnt/sdcard/(your folder)/customBootAnimation.zip", 
    "/system/media/bootanimation.zip"});
```

change the (your folder) to the folder on the sdcard containing the zip you want to install.
Hope this helped.